# С дочерьми или с дочерями?

Tags: орфография, склонение, существительные

Как правильно: ***с дочерьми*** или **с *дочерями***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оба варианта безусловно правильны.

Современная традиция - "с дочерьми".
Устаревающее "c дочерями" ошибкой не является, но используется чаще для стилизации или в стихотворном тексте.

Сейчас наблюдается общая тенденция стяжения окончания -ями после -ер-. Но этот процесс идет с разной скоростью.
Сравните: С дверьми - с дверями, со зверями - со зверьми, с матерями -  с (?)матерьми и проч.